# componentDidMount method not triggered when using inherited ES6 react class

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use ES6 classes inside of React, and want all my components to inherit certain methods, however as soon as I try to extend a component which extends the React.Component class, the componentDidMount method doesn't trigger and hence nothing gets rendered. The code I'm using:

BaseComponent.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class BaseComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();   
        console.log('BaseComponent constructor');
     }

     render() {
         return (
             <div>Hello, Im the base component</div>  
         );
     }
}

export default BaseComponent;
```

ExampleComponent.jsx

```
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';

class ExampleComponent extends BaseComponent {
     constructor(props) {

        super(props);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         console.log('exampleComponent mounted');
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello, Im the example component</div>  
        );
    }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
React.render(<ExampleComponent />, document.body);
```

I'm using React 0.13.3, and using babelify 6.1.2 to transpile.

The string 'exampleComponent mounted' never gets logged to console, and nothing is rendered. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem... I use a LoggedOutComponent and a LoggedInComponent as super classes, which redirects to the the loggedIn/loggedOut part of the app dpending on the logged-in state. But I can't get it to work... Have you found a solution for inheritance?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about the approach, but this code also works:

```
export default class Service extends BaseComponent {
  componentDidMount(...args) {
    super.componentDidMount.apply(this, args);
  }
}
```

UPD: this is considered to be a bad practice though:

a) https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/how-to-use-classes-and-sleep-at-night-9af8de78ccb4
b) https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in React 16.4.2, it only throws an exception.

Answer (score 4):

I think, the problem is that you cannot create deeper class-structures for react components. Also, you shouldn't have to need it. On your example the `BaseComponent` is useless anyway.

Try this instead:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         console.log('exampleComponent mounted');
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello, Im the example component</div>  
        );
    }
}
```

If you want to create 'BaseComponents', you could implement them as mixins or simply as 'sub components'.

This could look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';

export default class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         console.log('exampleComponent mounted');
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Hello, Im the example component</div>
                <BaseComponent />
            </div>  
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Also possible:

```
import React from 'react';
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';

export default class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         console.log('exampleComponent mounted');
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <BaseComponent
                <div>Hello, Im the example component</div>
            </BaseComponent>
        );
    }
}

// BaseComponent.js
render() {
    return {
        <div>
            <div>Hello, Im the base component</div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**: Above code works fine with es5/jsx syntax.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/tj4swy1p/)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware the example is useless, but I just made this to highlight the problem. I wasn't aware that React doesn't allow deeper class-structures. My project consists of a series of templates which have common functionality (and share the same states), so it made sense to try to put this in a base class. I've also read that mix-ins aren't available when using ES6 React classes - do you know anyway around this?

Comment: when you have some components that have the same state, you can use my second example. Create a new component with the state properties and that renders the part(s), that are always the same and render it in your specific component as you can see above.