# how to redefine a component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

There is a spa for react/redux. There is a component of Brands. The Media component is similar to it, but the data is retrieved from another Ajax request. I'm trying to inherit from Brands, but for some reason the componentDidMount is launched from Brands. How to do it right?

```
class Media extends Brands {
  loadData = async () => {
  alert('sdfdf'); //not displayed
    const { dispatch, dataList, clientId } = this.props;
    if (!dataList && clientId) {
      dispatch(mainLoaderActions.addBlockingRequest("loadMedia"));

      const res = await mediaApi.getBrandsData(clientId);

      dispatch(dataActions.setBrandsList(res));
      dispatch(mainLoaderActions.deleteBlockingRequest("loadMedia"));
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    alert('aaa'); //not displayed
    this.loadData();
  }

  render() {...
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072841/componentdidmount-method-not-triggered-when-using-inherited-es6-react-class 

Comment: The bottom paragraph on this page outlines the no-inheritance policy of react: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [componentDidMount method not triggered when using inherited ES6 react class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072841/componentdidmount-method-not-triggered-when-using-inherited-es6-react-class)

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't support class inheritance, hence your difficulty! See documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html There is an answer on a similar question here: [componentDidMount method not triggered when using inherited ES6 react class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072841/componentdidmount-method-not-triggered-when-using-inherited-es6-react-class) with an example of 'react' way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to accomplish by using HOC (higher order components). 
It will require to refactor both functions to reuse components common behavior in reactish way.
Check out this post from official react docs:
[Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

> A higher-order component (HOC) is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic.